# Is "A pointer is returned to an automatic variable" correct and unambiguous about what is "returned"?

Tags: word-order, attachment-ambiguity

I found this sentence in a book.

> A pointer is returned to an automatic variable in a previous function call (discussed in the section “Pointers to Local Data” on page 66).

Based on the context, I guess the author really mean *a pointer to an automatic variable is returned in a previous function call*. Is my understanding correct? If so, the current word order is a little bit misleading and it could let people think *we are returning a pointer to a variable*, which is pointless. Is the current word order correct?

Comment: In programming, pointers to objects (including variables) ***can*** be returned. In fact, it's a common technique. So, this is not an obvious error, or even necessarily an error at all. The most questionable thing about the sentence is calling something an ***automatic*** *variable*. I don't know what that means—although it's possible it's a variable type I've never heard of. But unless it is, that language doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the comment. *Automatic* variable here just means local variable and it's a C Language term. In the book, the author states that you should not return a pointer to a local variable out of a function. Because when the function completes, the local variable disappears and its memory can be reused.

Comment: Could it possibly mean "(a pointer to [an automatic variable in a previous function call]) is returned"?  I agree the word order is odd, and it should probably be broken into two sentences.

Comment: @JackOFlaherty It's hard to be sure without context, but that is my interpretation too (and I don't actually find the word order strange). Since the section title is "Pointers to Local Data," the book might be discussing the common mistake, in some languages like C/C++, of returning a pointer to variables that have gone or will go out of scope (this would be the case for variables of **automatic storage duration** in C++, also known as local variables).

Comment: @Justalearner Ah, okay. I had always heard of *local* and *global* variables when I used to work with C. It seems *automatic* is new terminology.

Comment: @JasonBassford: It is actually very old terminology. It's a storage class, to be contrasted with a `static`, `extern`, or `register` variable. You can actually write `auto int x;` in C (but not C++, which borrowed the `auto` keyword to do type inference), as long as you're within a function scope. In modern C, we would usually just write `int x;` because `auto` is the default anyway.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I'm familiar with `auto`. I didn't know that the full word was also used, so I didn't make that connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding may be correct.  I believe your rephrasing, "a pointer to an automatic variable is returned", is very likely what the original writer meant. That, however, leaves the final part of the sentence, "in a previous function call," to be placed with 'a pointer' or with 'an automatic variable'.

Based on its location in the original reference, I would assume the whole sentence would be rewritten, "A pointer to an automatic variable in a previous function call is returned."

It is unlikely that the original writer meant, "A pointer in a previous function call is returned to an automatic variable."

Since the original sentence is a bit confusing, as you note, it's difficult to know exactly what the writer meant.